# Why is the output of `conv2()` is divided by `sz^2`?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

The following routine subtract the mean value from the image making it sharper.

- im is an image matrix.
- sz is an integer.

How this routine works:

1. Image is first converted to double.
2. half of `sz` is used as pad-size value (which means this routine is going to apply convolution on the image).
3. m is height of the image, n is width of the image, o is no. of channels in the image.
4. 2d array of size `sz`x`sz` is initialized with 1s.
5. A for loop is declared which works on three iterations as this routine is going to apply the convolution operation on each of the channels.
6. `im(:,:,q)` means the filter is applied in-place.
7. `same` means the convolution operation returns the central part of the convolution, which is the same size as `im`. I.e. it is cropping the convolution output.

.

```
function pad = erase_mean(im, sz)    
    im = double(im);

    pad = floor(sz/2);
    [m,n,o] = size(im);

    mask = ones(sz,sz);

    for q=1:o       
        im(:,:,q)=double(im(:,:,q))-conv2(double(im(:,:,q)),mask,'same')./sz^2;

        mx=max(max(im(1+pad*2:m-pad*2,1+pad*2:n-pad*2,q)));

        im(:,:,q)=(im(:,:,q)./mx).*255;        
    end;

    mx = max(max(im(1+pad*2:m-pad*2,1+pad*2:n-pad*2,q)));
    im = uint8((im./mx(1)).*255);
    pad = im(1+pad*2:m-pad*2,1+pad*2:n-pad*2,:);
```

**Why is the output of `conv2()` is divided by `sz^2`?**

Comment: `pad` is an integer for nearly all of the function, but is a 3-dimensional matrix after the last line

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373546/why-is-this-question-massively-down-voted)

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: @ChanakaAmarasinghe, which part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

```
conv2(double(im(:,:,q)),mask,'same')./sz^2
```

is the same as

```
conv2(double(im(:,:,q)),mask./sz^2,'same')
```

This is because the convolution and the multiplication commute.

Thus, the convolution operation computes a local mean. Without the division, it would be a local sum.